# Extract JSON data in cell a1, into b1, c1, d1 etc.. - Excel

Tags: json, excel

```
{"fields":{"neTlAMGB-4yu9pN":"James","neTlAMGB-wmshSV":"james@mail.com","neTlAMGB-m446CO":"london, UK","neTlAMGB-0inhBf":"2016-12-15T12:00:00+00:00","neTlAMGB-TX6WrV":"07891122446699"}}
```

Ive exported some data from Trello into a CSV, some of the data have come in the above JSON format, if i have this data above in cell A1, id like to split it out into cells : b1, c2, d1, e1, f1, g1.

Is that possible with either some form of extract or regex or is there a JSON parser built into google spreadsheets / excel.

Ive created a demo google spreadsheet here for testing purposes : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rASBSSV4q9hC7IrxJNIFMlBOfYfkdLjJ7oyBVfniOPQ/edit#gid=0

--

Please note ive marked this question as "excel" and well as "google spreadsheets" as ive found in the past the majority of formula based scripts (non VBA) works cross platforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Json in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237345/import-json-in-excel)

Comment: @davejal, thanks, but not duplicate as that question is dealing with importing JSON into google drive in the first place using a script, im trying to extract data from a JSON object already in a cell, using a native spreadsheet function

Answer (score 0):

I think this actually does what you want

https://github.com/ronle/Json-To-Excel

To operate:

1. Open the table and click on "Button 1"
2. Acknowledge the welcome message
3. Click on "Build TreeView"
4. The script will create a treeview representing the Json file
5. Expand the tree and select "colorName" as the key value (place checkmark next to it)
6. Select the output tab & click the "Parse To Excel" button